# Whats the best, most simple ajax file uploader?

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, ajax

I have asp.net 3.5 website, and i want to put an ajax uploader, but i want this ajax uploader to:

1. don't refresh the page while/after uploading
2. easy to integrate
3. free
4. Not swf upload control
5. i will use it in uploading images, so want a simple way to get the uploaded image file name, and be able to tell it in which folder to upload to.

any one know a good one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a few different options out there.  I haven't used any of them, but I will most likely look into the 3rd option here in the near future.

- http://en.fileuploadajax.subgurim.net/
- http://ajaxuploader.com/
- http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/07/aspnet_file_upload_with_realti.html

Comment: I second Matt Berseth's file upload.

Comment: Matt Berseth's site is caught in a redirect; maybe the site has been hacked.  Anyone know where to download his control?

Answer (score 3):

Check http://krystalware.com/Products/SlickUpload/

Free trial never ends, but it puts a little "powered by" notice on your site.

Comment: looks like a great choice for ASP.NET

Comment: It is. I've used to to upload 50MB+ files without a problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use my [AJAX Upload plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) that allows you to use any element for file upload and doesn't require flash.