# ASP.Net Fileupload progressbar

Tags: asp.net

Is there any tutorial out there on how to write a FileUpload in asp.net with a progress bar? i cant find any of if there is a free component that would also work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a few different options out there. I haven't used any of them, but I will most likely look into the 3rd option here in the near future.

- http://en.fileuploadajax.subgurim.net/
- http://ajaxuploader.com/
- http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/07/aspnet_file_upload_with_realti.html

This post can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614945/whats-the-best-most-simple-ajax-file-uploader/615557#615557)...

Comment: Hi, how do they implemented progress bar in http://ajaxuploader.com/default.htm ?

Comment: does this use hidden iframes?

Answer (score 1):

I have used [NeatUpload](http://neatupload.codeplex.com/) on one of my projects in the past. I have not had any issues with it since I got it working.

The software is free and covered under LGPL License which is great if you're going to use this for work.

Answer (score -1):

The FileUpload control that ships with ASP.NET just transfers the file with the request payload. Therefore the only progressbar you'll get with it is the one at the bottom of your browser.  You'll have to go with a 3rd party solution.